# Change Photoshop language to English

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I installed localized version of Photoshop CS6.
Problem is, that all online tutorials are based on English version. So I want to change my UI language.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Go to where you installed Photoshop and find your locale folder, 
eg.

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6\Locales\pl_PL\Support Files
```

find file `tw10428.dat`and change  it's extension from tw10428.dat to tw10428.dak. Restart Photoshop, your menus are in English.

Comment: Menus yes, but unfortunately keyboard shortcuts are the way they were. I didn't find an easy solution for this.

Comment: thx man, u saved my life!

Comment: The fix didn't work for me, running CS6 Swedish version. Can't find anyone else having the same problem. Is there another fix?

Comment: This also works for a Photoshop CC on macOS with german localization, only that `tw10428.dat` is located at `/Applications/Adobe Photoshop CC/Locales/de_DE/Support Files/tw10428.dat`.